# How do I use a SMD crystal with 4 pins?

Tags: atmega328

I am running my arduino project with the atmega328 chip like this:

[image]

I have purchased by mistake [this crystal](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/SMD-Crystal-Resonators_XTY-7325-1600A2210-00_C389842.html):

[image]

The reason why I purchased by mistake that crystal was because it has this description:

> 16MHz ±10ppm 22pF 60Ω SMD-3225 SMD Crystal Resonators RoHS

I thought that it contained the 22pF ceramic capacitors inside. But latter I learned that I still the 22pf ceramic capacitors. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

**Anyways how can I use that crystal?** I only know how to connect the 2 pin crystal. Since this crystal has 4 pins now I am confused.

To me it makes sense to connect it like this:

1. Connect pins 9 and 10 from atmega --TO--> pins 1 and 3 from the crystal.
2. Connect pins 2 and 4 from crystal --TO--> Ground
3. Connect the 22pf ceramic capacitors to pins 1 and 3 from crystal and ground like in the first diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a nice question. Once for a project I stumbled upon this problem too.

The way you described the connection should work perfectly fine.

> To me it makes sense to connect it like this:
>   Connect pins 9 and 10 from atmega --TO--> pins 1 and 3 from the crystal.
>   Connect pins 2 and 4 from crystal --TO--> Ground
>   Connect the 22pf ceramic capacitors to pins 1 and 3 from crystal and ground like in the first diagram.

Keep it going and greetings from Switzerland.